# onSelectionChange only works intermittently

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been using onSelectionChange to act as a button to invoke a function ( Before that I tried using an image that I inserted, but the image kept moving around on the sheet).  Sometimes it works and other times not.  When it does not work nothing shows in the Executions log.  It can go for a long time without working, and then suddenly start working and will continue to work for a long time.  When it works it shows up in the Execution log.  I have not been making any changes to the onSelectionChange function.  This looks to me like a Google problem, but wanted to see if anyone else had run into this?

Here is a copy of the code:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  var cell = e.range;
  var activeSpreadSheet = e.source;
  var sheetName = activeSpreadSheet.getSheetName();
  var noInput = cell.isBlank();
  if(sheetName == "Input Forms" && noInput == false ){
    var column = cell.getColumn();
    var row = cell.getRow();
    if(column === 10 && row === 38){
      cell.setBackground("red");
      submitBaptismData();
    }
    else if(column === 10 && row === 37){
      cell.setBackground("red");
      submitBlessingData()
    }
    else if(column === 9 && row === 30){
      cell.setBackground("red");
      submitAaronicData()
    }
    Logger.log('Line 39');
  }
  return
}
```

Comment: Sometimes it can fail if too many changes are happening at the same time. All the same, can you share the code your onSelectionChange triggers?

Comment: You could change it to a onEdit function. Make a if statement to target one cell, in that cell make a checkbox. inside your code you can then run your code and uncheck it for the next time....?

Answer (score 1):

#### This seems like a bug

There is a issue opened in the issue tracker:

> https://issuetracker.google.com/178615259

Go give it a ☆ to subscribe and show that this affects you, or leave a comment if you have any relevant info to share.

<sup>(please comment with just a "+1" or similar - pressing the star is enough)</sup>